# JMeter No-Gui CSV Report adding additional column for some entries

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I have written a script that runs my JMeter script with an additional property file.

I have noticed depending on where I run the script from, the CSV output will sometimes have an additional column, meaning I can't generate the HTML report.

I was wondering if this has been seen before, or if it is a bug.

The script ends up running the following command - The idea being once the script has finished it auto generated the report.

`C:\apache-jmeter-5.6.2\bin\jmeter -n -t "C:\perfTesting\MicroApps\ViewBooking\ViewBooking_v1-0.jmx" -q "C:\perfTesting\MicroApps\ViewBooking\ViewBooking.properties" -l "C:\perfTesting\MicroApps\ViewBooking\Results\<dateOfWhenRan>\Summary_Report.csv" -e -o "C:\perfTesting\MicroApps\ViewBooking\Results\<dateOfWhenRan>\Output\"`

The script sits at `C:\perfTesting`

When I run it from here, my CSV produces the following output (Snippit)

> Look at lines 5 and 9 - For where the website url gets added
>
> Look at lines 4 and 8 - For where Latency is null (but the entry is still 17 cols instead of 16)

```
timeStamp,elapsed,label,responseCode,responseMessage,threadName,dataType,success,failureMessage,bytes,sentBytes,grpThreads,allThreads,Latency,IdleTime,Connect
1708972397808,406,0.0 - Login,200,"Number of samples in transaction : 1, number of failing samples : 0",View Booking-ThreadStarter 2-1,,true,,1342,798,1,2,0,167,310
1708972397967,406,001 - login,200,OK,View Booking-ThreadStarter 2-1,text,true,,1342,798,1,2,403,0,310
1708972397808,406,0.0 - Login,200,"Number of samples in transaction : 1, number of failing samples : 0",View Booking-ThreadStarter 2-1,,true,,1342,798,1,2,null,0,167,310
1708972397967,406,001 - login,200,OK,View Booking-ThreadStarter 2-1,text,true,,1342,798,1,2,<Website Url it is hitting>,403,0,310
1708972397801,442,0.0 - Login,200,"Number of samples in transaction : 1, number of failing samples : 0",My Bookings-ThreadStarter 1-1,,true,,1341,798,1,2,0,167,310
1708972397967,442,001 - login,200,OK,My Bookings-ThreadStarter 1-1,text,true,,1341,798,1,2,442,0,310
1708972397801,442,0.0 - Login,200,"Number of samples in transaction : 1, number of failing samples : 0",My Bookings-ThreadStarter 1-1,,true,,1341,798,1,2,null,0,167,310
1708972397967,442,001 - login,200,OK,My Bookings-ThreadStarter 1-1,text,true,,1341,798,1,2,<Website Url it is hitting>,442,0,310
1708972398815,77,0.0 - Login,200,"Number of samples in transaction : 1, number of failing samples : 0",View Booking-ThreadStarter 2-2,,true,,1340,798,2,3,0,3,13
1708972398816,77,001 - login,200,OK,View Booking-ThreadStarter 2-2,text,true,,1340,798,2,3,77,0,13
```

[Image of the same code but coloured so can easily spot the issues](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEETi.png)

This means when the report tries to generate I get the classic `Mismatch between expected number of columns:16 and columns in CSV file:17, check your jmeter.save.saveservice.* configuration or check if line 11 in 'C:\PerfTesting\MicroApps\ViewBooking\Results\2024-02-26-19-02\Summary_Report.csv' is complete` which is down to some of the entries having the `<Website Url it is hitting>`

Now if I run the following command `jmeter -n -t "C:\perfTesting\MicroApps\ViewBooking\ViewBooking_v1-0.jmx" -q "C:\perfTesting\MicroApps\ViewBooking\ViewBooking.properties"` in the `C:\apache-jmeter-5.6.2\bin\` directory, it produces the CSV perfectly, and I can then generate the report separately.

I'm currently testing what happens if I run the the test and try to generator the report from the `C:\apache-jmeter-5.6.2\bin\` directory.

But I was wondering if anyone might know why the location of running the script would make the CSV produce different entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In classic developer fashion, I spent hours looking for an answer, eventually giving up and asking for help, to go then and solve the problem.

## The Cause

In Jmeter V5.6.2 the `jmeter.save.saveservice.url` property in the `apache-jmeter-5.6.2\bin\jmeter.properties` file is set to `true`, and when using the `-l` flag in non-gui mode, JMeter will create a global listener using these properties

In my `JMX` file I had a listener that was enabled and outputting the report to the exact same location - however, this listener had `Save Url` set to false.

It turns out the global listener and the one I had enabled in Jmeter were clashing and combining the results, resulting in an invalid CSV which had entries of both 16 and 17 columns.

## Fix

Disable the Listener In the `JMX` file

Answer (score 0):

Location of the script doesn't matter, what matters is [Results File Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config).

So my expectation is that you're running one JMeter from `C:\apache-jmeter-5.6.2\bin\` and another one from another location which is in your operating system [PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable))

So you need to either decide which JMeter to use or sync their properties.

More information:

- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-properties-customization)